# Seg fault after pthread_create (

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is seg faulting.

It is seg faulting in

```
get_ranks_parallel
```

on the line

```
for (struct node* node = data->plist->head; node!=NULL; node=node->next)
```

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct args args;
struct args
{
    list* qlist;
    double damps;
    double dampening;
    int j;
    int n_cores;
    int n_pages;
    double *rank_current;
    double *rank_previous;
};

//int cond;
int i;
void pagerank(list* plist, int ncores, int npages, int nedges, double dampener)
{
    int num_pages = npages;
    args* data = malloc(sizeof(data));
    
    //data = malloc(sizeof(args) + num_pages * sizeof(double));
    data->damps = (1-dampener)/npages;   //eg (1-0.85/4)
    double damp = (1-dampener)/npages;
    data->qlist = plist;
    //store pageranks into  arrays of doubles
    double rank_prev[npages];   //previous ranks
    double rank_curr[npages];   //current ranks
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < npages; i++)
    {
        rank_prev[i] = (double)1/npages;   //must cast either 1 or npages as a double to get output as a double
        rank_curr[i] = (double)1/npages;
    }
    
    data->dampening = dampener;  //for use inside parallel function
    int stop = 1; 
    data->n_cores = ncores;   //for use inside parallel function
    int num_cores = data->n_cores;

    pthread_t thread_id[num_cores];
    
    while(stop == 1)
    {   
        //if more than one core, parallelise
        //else solve sequentially
        if (ncores > 1)
        {
            pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock, NULL);
            for (data->j = 0; data->j < num_cores; data->j++)
            {
                //thread_args[k] = k;    //(plist, damp, dampener,  rank_prev, rank_curr, i, num_cores)
                pthread_create(&thread_id[data->j], NULL, &get_ranks_parallel, NULL);   
            }
                
            for (data->j = 0; data->j < num_cores; data->j++)
            {
                pthread_join(thread_id[data->j], NULL);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < npages; i++)
            {
                rank_prev[i] = data->rank_previous[i];
                rank_curr[i] = data->rank_current[i] ;
            }
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_lock);
        }
        else
        {
            get_ranks_seq(plist, damp, dampener, rank_prev, rank_curr);
        }
        
        stop = check_converge(rank_curr, rank_prev, npages);
        update_prev(rank_curr, rank_prev, npages);
    }
    print_ranks(rank_curr, plist);
}



void * get_ranks_parallel(void * q)
{
    
    args * data = (struct args *) q;
    data = malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    //store pageranks into  arrays of doubles
    data->rank_previous[data->n_pages];   //previous ranks
    data->rank_current[data->n_pages];  //current ranks
    
    //initialise_rank(rank_prev, rank_curr, npages);   //initialise both rank arrays, setting all values a 1/N
    for (i = 0; i < data->n_pages; i++)
    {
        data->rank_previous[i] = (double)1/data->n_pages;   //must cast either 1 or npages as a double to get output as a double
        data->rank_current[i] = (double)1/data->n_pages;
    }
    //loops through all the pages
    for (struct node* node = data->qlist->head; node!=NULL; node=node->next)
    {
        //calling page from current node in list 
        page* p = node->page;
        
        //thread will operate on rooms with index the same as thread id initially, then thread id +ncores, so all threads work on the same amount of rooms
        if ((node->page->index) == data->j)
        {
            //check to make sure inlinks list is not empty
            double sum = 0.0;
            if (p->inlinks!=NULL)
            {   
                //loops through the inlinks list that is associated with current page
                for (struct node* inNode = p->inlinks->head; inNode != NULL; inNode = inNode->next)
                {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
                    sum += data->rank_previous[inNode->page->index] / inNode->page->noutlinks;     //calculations on current page using inlinks list associated with it
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
                }   
            }
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
            data->rank_current[node->page->index] = data->damps + data->dampening*sum;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
        data->j += data->n_cores;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
    }
    //free(args);
}
```

plist and inlinks are both linked lists set up in the header file, so all I'm doing is taking those and all of the parameters and using them to calculate the "pageranks" of all the pages and storing them into an array.
plist stores page structs (p), which each in turn store a linked list (inlist)

I have to make it run as fast as I can hence the threads

Its creating the thread, then giving a seg fault when it tries to loop through the linked list plist. There is obviously something wrong with where my pointers are going, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Threading this program has been a nightmare.

If it helps, this is the function written normally without taking all arguments as void *
Basically it runs fine when the program  runs through the sequential function, but seg faults when trying to loop through plist in the parallel function.

```
void get_ranks_seq(list* plist, double damp, double dampener, double rank_prev[], double rank_curr[])
{
    //loops through all the pages
    for (struct node* node = plist->head; node!=NULL; node=node->next)
    {
        //calling page from current node in list 
        page* p = node->page;
        //check to make sure inlinks list is not empty
        double sum = 0.0;
        if (p->inlinks!=NULL)
        {   
            //loops through the inlinks list that is associated with current page
            for (struct node* inNode = p->inlinks->head; inNode != NULL; inNode = inNode->next)
            {
                sum += rank_prev[inNode->page->index] / inNode->page->noutlinks;     //calculations on current page using inlinks list associated with it
            }   
        }
        rank_curr[node->page->index] = damp + dampener*sum;
    }
}
```

Sorry if this doesnt make much sense, any help would be really appreciated!

---

**Update**:

I get this error from valgrind:

```
==5337== Thread 2: 
==5337== Invalid read of size 4 
==5337== at 0x4017A8: get_ranks_parallel (in /.automount/net/ufiler5/u3/cs1/lsin8526/comp2129_2013/assignment4/assignment4/pa‌​gerank) 
==5337== by 0x3252607D14: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so) 
==5337== by 0x3251EF246C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so) 
==5337== Address 0x20 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd –
```

Comment: I bet either `data`, `plist` or `node` points to invalid memory or simply is `NULL`. Valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Shouldn't this `args* data = malloc(sizeof(data));` be `args* data = malloc(sizeof(*data));`

Comment: plist and node should be fine, as it works fine in the sequential version of the function. 

I've messed up putting all the arguments into the struct so the function can be passed into pthread_create somehow...

Comment: Please compile your code with debugging set to on (usually `-g`). Then valgrind or even a debugger may tell you exactly the line that is faulting. In any case such online debugging is not really appropriate for SO, this too localized as a question, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
args* data = malloc(sizeof(data));
```

only allocates 4 (32 bit OS) or 8 bytes (64 bytes OS), the size of pointer.

This is to few, as you want as many bytes as `args` needs.

Allocating to few, provokes Undefined Behaviuor when later access the objects members.

So you might like to mod your code like this:

```
args* data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
```

---

Some more issies:

Overwriting value of `data`:

```
args * data = (struct args *) q;
data = malloc(sizeof(struct args));
//store pageranks into  arrays of doubles
```

Useless code (does nothing):

```
data->rank_previous[data->n_pages];   //previous ranks
data->rank_current[data->n_pages];  //current ranks

//initialise_rank(rank_prev, rank_curr, npages);   //initialise both rank arrays, setting all values a 1/N
```

As malloc() does **not** initialise memory the next line provokes Undefined Behavior, as accessesing unitialized variables does:

```
for (i = 0; i < data->n_pages; i++)
{
  ...
```

Comment: That didn't fix it unfortunately. It's still creating the thread and immediately seg faulting

Comment: Crap can't believe I hadn't assigned n_pages. Did not solve the problem though

Comment: So after fixing the uninitialised values, I get this error from valgrind:


==5337== Thread 2:
==5337== Invalid read of size 4
==5337==    at 0x4017A8: get_ranks_parallel (in /.automount/net/ufiler5/u3/cs1/lsin8526/comp2129_2013/assignment4/assignment4/pagerank)
==5337==    by 0x3252607D14: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.16.so)
==5337==    by 0x3251EF246C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==5337==  Address 0x20 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: "*... at 0x4017A8: get_ranks_parallel ...`*" ths is where in your code as posted in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
args * data = (struct args *) q;
```

and then immediately after,

```
data = malloc(sizeof(struct args));
```

making `data` point to uninitialized memory, so `data->qlist` is `NULL` at the beginning of the loop. Not sure what you were trying to do, but there's your problem.

Comment: "*... so data->qlist is NULL ...*" it could be any value, as `malloc()` does not set the allocated memory to `0`.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense. Still seg faulting however :(